# Use linq to check if the contents of an array are in a column in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a function that returns a list of ids based on a separate selection. This function returns all the ids and they are displayed as checkboxes in the view. Once I select some of the checkboxes, they are saved to the database as a comma delimited string. When editing the selections, the user needs to be able to deselect selected check boxes and select alternate ones. The issue I have is how to set the checkboxes as checked that exist in comma delimited string in the database. I have a linq statement that creates an array of strings, but I'm not sure how  to check any of the checkboxes that are in the array based on their ID.

Here are the functions in the ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocNamesByDocTypeIdList()
{
    using (var db = new ARXEntities())
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> docName = new List<SelectListItem>();
        docName = (from t in db.vwMapDocNamesToSecurityUsers
                   select new 
                   { 
                       t.DocName, 
                       t.DocNameId, 
                       t.DocTypeId 
                   }).Distinct()
                   .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                   {
                       Text = x.DocName,
                       Value = x.DocNameId.ToString(),
                       Group = new SelectListGroup() { Name = x.DocTypeId.ToString() }
                   }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
         var docCount = docName.Count();
         return docName;
    }
}

public String[] GetDocNamesForDocTypeId(int? docTypeId)
{
    var nameCkBoxes = DocNamesByDocTypeIdList().Where(m => m.Group.Name == docTypeId.ToString()).ToString().Split(',');
    //Set the ids in the array as checked in the view?

    return nameCkBoxes;
 }
```

Foreach loop in the view:

```
<div class="ckDocNames">
    @foreach (var dn in Model.GetDocNamesForDocTypeId(Model.DocTypeId))
    {
        <div class="checkboxContainer, editCkBoxes">
            <input class="ckBoxes" type="checkbox" name="DocNameId" value="@dn.Value" dtid="@dn.Group.Name" />@dn.Text<br />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Why are your storing your selections as a comma separated string instead of using a relational database? Why are you using `SelectListItem` (which is for generating a dropdownlist)? Since `GetDocNamesForDocTypeId` returns `string[]`, `@dn.Value` and `@dn.Group.Name` make no sense. And since you only appear to be generating checkboxes for items that you previously stored as checked, there are no _alternate ones_ to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33246684/2907017) and also from [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247202/2907017) :)
you can

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetDocNamesForFilterId(int id)
{
    using (var db = new ARXEntities())
    {
        var selectedIds = (from t in db.ServiceAccountFilters
                    where t.FilterId == id
                    select t.DocNameId).ToList();
        return selectedIds;
    }
}
```

and in the `FilterModel` add new property for the selectedIds

```
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedDocNames { get; set; }
```

and in the GET `Edit` Action add this

```
var model = new FilterViewModel 
{
   ...
   SelectedDocNames = GetDocNamesForFilterId(serviceAccountFilter.FilterId);
};
```

and in your view you should populate all checkboxes and just check what is choosen before like below to let the user check or uncheck any one in the edit mode

```
@foreach (var dn in Model.DocNamesByDocTypeIdList())
{
    <div class="checkboxContainer">
        <input class="ckBoxes" type="checkbox" name="selectedDocIds" checked="@Model.SelectedDocNames.Contains(int.Parse(dn.Value))" value="@dn.Value" dtid="@dn.Group.Name" />@dn.Text<br />
    </div>
 }
```

and in the POST action just check what are selected by the user as below

```
var selectedIds = form.GetValues("selectedDocIds");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses Sherif.

Comment: GetDocNamesForFilterId above wont work since DocNameId is a string. Don't get mad at me, this database has been in use for years. :)

Comment: True and I did that, its the checked="@Model.SelectedDocNames.Contains(int.Parse(dn.Value))" that will not work as a result since you cannot use a .Contains() with a string?

Comment: .Contains() is for the `IEnumerable<>` ... change all of `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<string>`